# For loops cannot find symbol Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

Beginner at Java here. I cannot figure why I am getting a cannot find symbol on line 16.

```
package loops;


public class forloops {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    int loopVal;
    int end_value = 11;
    int addition = 0;

    for (loopVal = 0; loopVal < end_value; loopVal++) {

        System.out.prinln("Loop Value = " + loopVal);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Which line is 16? What symbol can't be found?

Comment: Nevermind, it was System.out.println("Loop Value = " + loopVal);

It's been a long day

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is `System.out.println(..)`

You wrote `System.out.prinln(..)`, where the compiler does not find the method `prinln`

Comment: Wouldn't that give a "method prinln(String) in undefined for the type PrintStream" error?  Usually "cannot find symbol" errors are caused by an undeclared variable.

Comment: Just tried it. It gives me: `Test.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
  System.out.prinln("");
`